# c# Insert statement - array as sql column name

Tags: c#, sql, syntax-error

I have two tables, `Vehicle_Status` and `Trans_Income`.

`Vehicle_Status` contain two columns, `Vehicle_Number` and `Status`, and the `Vehicle_Number` consists the data which are the column name of `Trans_Income`.

I want to load the data from `Vehicle_Number` into an array and use it in the `insert` statement.

```
string[] vehicleActive = new string[100];

SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select Vehicle_Number from [dbo].[Vehicle_Status] Where Status = 'Inactive'", con);
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

con.Open();
int a = 0;

SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

while (dr.Read())
{
    vehicleActive[a] = dr["Vehicle_Number"].ToString();
    a++;
}

con.close();

for (int b = 0; b < a; b++)
{
    cmd = new SqlCommand("Insert Into [dbo].[Trans_Income](Month, Particular,'"+vehicleActive[b]+"') VALUES (@Month, @Particular, @vehicleNo )", con);

    con.Open();

    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Month", textBox2.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Particular", textBox2.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@vehicleNo", textBox3.Text);

    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    con.Close();    
}
```

But I get the error

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Incorrect syntax near 'BJW6719'.'

One of the column names is `BJW6719` - can anyone help me with this? Or is there any other, better way for doing this? Thank you in advance.

Comment: It sounds like your mixing data and metadata together which is usually a bad sign for a data model. You have multiple columns containing the same "type" of data. Usually, that data should be stored in a *single* column and an additional column should contain the *data* that is currently being embedded in your column *names*.

Comment: Hi @Damien_The_Unbeliever Thank You for your advice, this is part of my program, I am trying to record transport income of the vehicle under same order number, and some time need to get the average and insert into all "active" vehicle, i am not sure if i am doing this correctly, so is it better to have more row than more column in this case? ThankYou

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I notice you have extra ' character around your column name, they are not required. Try with the below code:

```
cmd = new SqlCommand("Insert Into [dbo].[Trans_Income](Month, Particular,"+vehicleActive[b]+") VALUES (@Month, @Particular, @vehicleNo )", con);
```

Are you sure that your third column name is: `BJW6719`. If yes the above will work otherwise you need to add the correct column name.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using .net framework 4.5 up then you can simply convert table into arrey here is code

```
try
                {
                  var dt = new DataTable();
                  var cmd = new SqlCommand();
                  cmd.CommandText = @"Select Vehicle_Number from [dbo].[Vehicle_Status] Where Status = 'Inactive'";
                                   var da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                  da.Fill(dt);
                }
             catch (Exception ex)
                {

                }
             finally
                {
                  if (cmd.Connection.State == ConnectionState.Open)
                   {
                     cmd.Connection.Close();
                   }
                }

               var vehicleActive= dt.Rows[0].ItemArray.Select(x => x.ToString()).ToArray();
```

then you can loop through your array like this

```
for (int i = 0; i < vehicleActive.Length; i++)
                    {
                        cmd = new SqlCommand("Insert Into [dbo].[Trans_Income](Month, Particular,'"+vehicleActive[b]+"') VALUES (@Month, @Particular, @vehicleNo )", con);

                        con.Open();


                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Month", textBox2.Text);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Particular", textBox2.Text);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@vehicleNo", textBox3.Text);

                        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        con.Close();    
                     }
```

this is better way to loop through database from code and there might be issue with column name so check column name from sql server before defining in sql query from code